# Correct image size in image mosaic

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, surf, mosaic

I'm implementing image mosaic in Matlab using SURF.the problem is

```
outputView = imref2d(size(img1)*2);
Ir = imwarp(img2,tform,'OutputView',outputView);
```

it produces

[image]

i want it something like this

[image]

if i change

```
outputView = imref2d(size(img1)*2);
```

to

```
outputView = imref2d(size(img1));
```

matlab crops the second image so it can fit in first image size after transforming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that when you warp the image with respect to the target plane, many of the pixels in this new plane are equal to 0.  A very rudimentary algorithm is to simply threshold your image so that you find values above 0 then find the largest bounding box that encompasses the non-zero pixels... then crop:

```
[rows,cols] = find(Ir(:,:,1) > 0);
topLeftRow = min(rows);
topLeftCol = min(cols);
bottomRightRow = max(rows);
bottomRightCol = max(cols);

Ir_crop = Ir(topLeftRow:bottomRightRow, topLeftCol:bottomRightCol, :);
```

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in SURF_with_MATALB (line 55)
Ir_crop = Ir(topLeftRow:bottomRightRow, topLeftCol:bottomRightCol, :);

size(Ir)= 898        1354           3
topLeftRow = 1
bottomRightRow =   476
topLeftCol =   250
bottomRightCol = 3706

Comment: Change the first line to `[rows,cols] = find(Ir(:,:,1) > 0);` and it should work.

Comment: Not sure if we are talking about the same, but I remember when creating mosaic software at university that an easy way to do the projection if reverse projection. You project the target plane to the original image, this way each pixel of the target gets assigned to a pixel in the source, avoiding the problem of the zeros.

Comment: Right, I forgot it was a colour image.  The modification by @erfan works. I've edited my post.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I can't tell if those perforations in the transformed images are holes due to the forward transformation... or if that's actually part of the design on the wall. lol.